# How to temporarily ban an IP address, after "n" number of SSH login failures?

Tags: ssh, iptables, login, pam, limit

How can I limit SSH login attempts per minute per IP ?

I want to disable login attempts during 5 seconds after a failure. Is this possible ? I'm not talking about ban a user after parsing logs like Fail2ban.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Question 1**

This can be done with the module `hashlimit`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m hashlimit \
  --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above 3/minute -j DROP
```

**Question 2**

Netfilter does not see login failures only connections. You need a tool (like Fail2ban) which is active on both levels. You could create a chain with blocked IPs and run a script after each login failure which would do something like

```
iptables -A blocked_ips -s $evil_ip -j DROP
sleep 5
iptables -D blocked_ips -s $evil_ip -j DROP
```

Comment: using the answer on Q1 (hashlimit) block my terminal after a few seconds, even on currently connected session..

Answer (score 7):

Look at iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 2 -j DROP
```

It will permit only 1 new connection per IP per 5 seconds.

Comment: Why --hitcount 2 and not 1 ?

Comment: @Edgar because you need to drop the second new packet, not the first one. `--hitcount` indicates the packet number to process greater than or equal to the given value.

Comment: Good technique, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

The component in charge of the authentication on a GNU/Linux system is PAM (Pluggable Authentication System).

You can configure it by adding modules. One interesting module in your case could be `pam_tally`. It's used to limit the number of login attempts and ban users.

If you add this line in one of the `/etc/pam.d/` configuration file:

```
auth     required       pam_tally.so deny=1 unlock_time=5 per_user
```

you prevent a user who failed to login to attempt again within the next five seconds. So, you limit the number of connection attempts per minute to 12.

References:

- [A post on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/394505/how-to-lock-linux-user-account-after-certain-unsuccessful-attempts)
- [PAM_tally man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tally)

Comment: But that is on a much higher level, consuming orders of magnitude more CPU load than throwing away connection requests in Netfilter.

Comment: That's true. If the goal is only to protect SSH, I'd prefer the netfilter option too. But it's never a bad idea to use two security mechanisms for the same purpose as long as they don't conflict with each other.

Comment: @lgeorget : Use pam_tally and netfilter/iptables is the best answer to my problem ?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion, that'd definitely be a good combination to protect your system.

Answer (score 2):

### Deny 5 seconds after 1 login attempt fail

**pam_tally.so:**

> This module maintains a count of attempted accesses, can reset count
>   on success, can deny access if too many attempts fail. pam_tally comes
>   in two parts: pam_tally.so and pam_tally. The former is the PAM module
>   and the latter, a stand-alone program. pam_tally is an (optional)
>   application which can be used to interrogate and manipulate the
>   counter file. It can display users’ counts, set individual counts, or
>   clear all counts. Setting artificially high counts may be useful for
>   blocking users without changing their passwords. For example, one
>   might find it useful to clear all counts every midnight from a cron
>   job. The faillog(8) command can be used instead of pam_tally to to
>   maintain the counter file.

Normally, failed attempts to access root will not cause the root account to become blocked, to prevent denial-of-service: if your users aren’t given shell accounts and root may only login via su or at the machine console (not telnet/rsh, etc), this is safe

Step 1# edit “`/etc/pam.d/system-auth`” and append following line below “`pam_env.so`”

```
auth required pam_tally.so deny=1 lock_time=5
account required pam_tally.so reset
```

after configuring above file try to login with wrong password of any user
here is sample output of my logfile

logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/secure
Jun 04 15:59:13 station01 su: pam_tally(su-l:auth): user test (502) has time limit [167s left] since last failure
Jun 26 16:01:35 station01 sshd[13890]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): user test1 (503) has time limit [174s left] since last failure.
Jun 26 16:01:37 station01 sshd[13890]: Failed password for test1 from 192.168.0.13 port 54398 ssh2
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside you /etc/ssh/sshd_config file there is a directive that I believe will help you.

```
MaxAuthTries 6
```

Here is the MaxAuthTries defination from the man pages:

> MaxAuthTries - Specifies the maximum number of authentication attempts permitted per connection.  Once the number of failures reaches half this value, additional failures are logged.  The default is 6.

Comment: ... but it's not a limit _per minute_.